# Unable to install CBLAS

Tags: software-installation, compiling, make

I have extracted the .tgz downloaded from [here](http://www.netlib.org/blas/#_cblas) and made the following changes in Makefile.in:

```
BLLIB = /home/at3ee/CBLAS/lib/cblas_LINUX.a
```

However, the following error occurs:

```
make all
( cd src && make all)
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/at3ee/CBLAS/src'
ar r  ../lib/cblas_LINUX.a cblas_srotg.o cblas_srotmg.o cblas_srot.o cblas_srotm.o cblas_sswap.o cblas_sscal.o  cblas_scopy.o cblas_saxpy.o cblas_sdot.o  cblas_sdsdot.o cblas_snrm2.o cblas_sasum.o cblas_isamax.o   sdotsub.o   sdsdotsub.o snrm2sub.o sasumsub.o isamaxsub.o  cblas_drotg.o cblas_drotmg.o cblas_drot.o cblas_drotm.o cblas_dswap.o cblas_dscal.o  cblas_dcopy.o cblas_daxpy.o cblas_ddot.o  cblas_dsdot.o cblas_dnrm2.o cblas_dasum.o cblas_idamax.o   ddotsub.o   dsdotsub.o       dnrm2sub.o dasumsub.o idamaxsub.o cblas_cswap.o cblas_cscal.o cblas_csscal.o cblas_ccopy.o cblas_caxpy.o cblas_cdotu_sub.o cblas_cdotc_sub.o cblas_icamax.o cdotcsub.o cdotusub.o icamaxsub.o  cblas_zswap.o cblas_zscal.o cblas_zdscal.o cblas_zcopy.o cblas_zaxpy.o cblas_zdotu_sub.o cblas_zdotc_sub.o cblas_dznrm2.o cblas_dzasum.o cblas_izamax.o zdotcsub.o zdotusub.o dzasumsub.o  dznrm2sub.o  izamaxsub.o  cblas_scasum.o scasumsub.o cblas_scnrm2.o scnrm2sub.o cblas_sgemv.o cblas_sgbmv.o cblas_sger.o cblas_ssbmv.o  cblas_sspmv.o cblas_sspr.o  cblas_sspr2.o cblas_ssymv.o cblas_ssyr.o  cblas_ssyr2.o cblas_stbmv.o cblas_stbsv.o cblas_stpmv.o cblas_stpsv.o  cblas_strmv.o cblas_strsv.o   cblas_dgemv.o cblas_dgbmv.o cblas_dger.o cblas_dsbmv.o  cblas_dspmv.o cblas_dspr.o  cblas_dspr2.o cblas_dsymv.o cblas_dsyr.o  cblas_dsyr2.o cblas_dtbmv.o cblas_dtbsv.o cblas_dtpmv.o cblas_dtpsv.o  cblas_dtrmv.o cblas_dtrsv.o   cblas_cgemv.o cblas_cgbmv.o cblas_chemv.o cblas_chbmv.o cblas_chpmv.o cblas_ctrmv.o cblas_ctbmv.o cblas_ctpmv.o cblas_ctrsv.o cblas_ctbsv.o cblas_ctpsv.o cblas_cgeru.o cblas_cgerc.o cblas_cher.o  cblas_cher2.o cblas_chpr.o  cblas_chpr2.o  cblas_zgemv.o cblas_zgbmv.o cblas_zhemv.o cblas_zhbmv.o cblas_zhpmv.o cblas_ztrmv.o cblas_ztbmv.o cblas_ztpmv.o cblas_ztrsv.o cblas_ztbsv.o cblas_ztpsv.o cblas_zgeru.o cblas_zgerc.o cblas_zher.o  cblas_zher2.o cblas_zhpr.o  cblas_zhpr2.o  cblas_sgemm.o cblas_ssymm.o cblas_ssyrk.o cblas_ssyr2k.o cblas_strmm.o cblas_strsm.o cblas_dgemm.o cblas_dsymm.o cblas_dsyrk.o cblas_dsyr2k.o cblas_dtrmm.o cblas_dtrsm.o   cblas_cgemm.o cblas_csymm.o cblas_chemm.o cblas_cherk.o cblas_cher2k.o cblas_ctrmm.o cblas_ctrsm.o  cblas_csyrk.o cblas_csyr2k.o cblas_zgemm.o cblas_zsymm.o cblas_zhemm.o cblas_zherk.o cblas_zher2k.o cblas_ztrmm.o cblas_ztrsm.o  cblas_zsyrk.o cblas_zsyr2k.o cblas_globals.o cblas_xerbla.o xerbla.o  
echo ../lib/cblas_LINUX.a
../lib/cblas_LINUX.a
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/at3ee/CBLAS/src'
( cd testing && make all )
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/at3ee/CBLAS/testing'
gfortran  -o xscblat1 c_sblat1.o c_sblas1.o ../lib/cblas_LINUX.a /home/at3ee/CBLAS/lib/cblas_LINUX.a 
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(cblas_srotg.o): in function `cblas_srotg':
cblas_srotg.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `srotg_'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(cblas_srot.o): in function `cblas_srot':
cblas_srot.c:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `srot_'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(cblas_sswap.o): in function `cblas_sswap':
cblas_sswap.c:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `sswap_'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(cblas_sscal.o): in function `cblas_sscal':
cblas_sscal.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `sscal_'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(cblas_scopy.o): in function `cblas_scopy':
cblas_scopy.c:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `scopy_'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(cblas_saxpy.o): in function `cblas_saxpy':
cblas_saxpy.c:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `saxpy_'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(sdotsub.o): in function `sdotsub_':
sdotsub.f:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `sdot_'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(snrm2sub.o): in function `snrm2sub_':
snrm2sub.f:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `snrm2_'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(sasumsub.o): in function `sasumsub_':
sasumsub.f:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `sasum_'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(isamaxsub.o): in function `isamaxsub_':
isamaxsub.f:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `isamax_'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(scasumsub.o): in function `scasumsub_':
scasumsub.f:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `scasum_'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/cblas_LINUX.a(scnrm2sub.o): in function `scnrm2sub_':
scnrm2sub.f:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `scnrm2_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:72: xscblat1] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/at3ee/CBLAS/testing'
make: *** [Makefile:180: alltst] Error 2
```

Kindly suggest. Thanks,

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Why do you compile CBLAS? What was wrong with binary [deb-packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=blas%20dev) from official repository? For which application you compile CBLAS?

Comment: My Ubuntu version: 20.04. I needed it for installing wav2letter whose steup.py was resulting in error: Unable to find cblas.

Comment: Please provide all the details to make your question reproducible. Exact steps done, executed commands and download URLs for used software.

Comment: @N0rbert Please write an answer about how to install the repository version of blas (I don't want to write the answer because you already posted the solution in the comment). Most likely that will work for OP. Maybe OP does not know about its existence (or how to install it). Also, libopenblas is much faster than libblas.

Answer (score 1):

To have fully-featured support of linear algebra libraries in your Ubuntu system you have to execute the following commands

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev libblas64-dev libatlas-base-dev liblapack-dev libopenblas-dev libgsl-dev
```

and then retry running `setup.py`.

---

For more successful Ubuntu usage you have to know its packages resource, it is located at https://packages.ubuntu.com/ ; it provides search for [package names](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libblas&searchon=names) and [contents](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=focal&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=cblas.a&searchon=contents).